# How to reliably teardown and reconnect a TCP/IP socket with AT Commands

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, at-command, 3g

I have a problem which I feel I have almost solved, but am stuck at the "last leg".
I've been working on it for a few days now, and although have had breakthroughs, feel I 
am still a way off a workable solution - due to a few blind spots.

I have an embedded, mobile firmware application (which I can't edit directly), which is having trouble 
re-connecting to our server over TCP/IP/UMTS/GSM. The firmware uses AT commands only to initiate and 
control the connection, via a modem. The original version of our product has been 
working in production for around 10 years, however a "new" version of the hardware is 
experiencing intermittent problems.

There are many variables but I have ruled out all but one: the modem chip.

- We have new versions of the firmware with various changes, but extensive A/B 
  testing has shown all firmware experiences the same problem, so I have ruled it out.
- We have a legacy VB6 server, using Winsock. I have recently written a simpler Node.js 
  version which also demonstrates the same problem almost identically (amazingly so).
- We use various telco's: Optus, Vodafone, Telstra. Again they seem irrelevant to the issue.
- We use direct telcos, or resellers with their own private network (APN). Again proved irrelevant.
- We have different hosting/network installations, but again I've tested many configurations 
  including our corporate network, production hosting, AWS dev EC2s and they all perform 
  pretty much the same.
- We also have automated tests with emulated/mock versions of the hardware/firmware 
  which has shown the various servers and networks all seems to operate well and similarly.
- The final variant which shows significant - actually absolute - difference is between the 
  Telit UC864 modem and the HE910. The former, older modem works perfectly, but the newer HE910
  experiences the problem always. I have tested all possible permutations, and the problem
  follows the HE910.

Of course I have endlessly read the Telit documentation (specifically "Easy IP", and 
the AT command, and software references) but cannot see much advertised difference 
between the two products. The HE910 is in a physical package by Glynn but I don't believe 
that affects its behaviour.

The problem:

Our firmware application connects to our server on a specific port/address. The server 
initiates an outbound application protocol to which the firmware must respond. (So really 
the firmware is the "server" but this doesn't matter.) It's very lightweight and simple, 
in the order of 10s of bytes per command/response.

The problem arises when the firmware re-connects, due to an event, "on top of" an existing 
socket connection. The firmware always follows the same process: teardown, configure, 
connect - regardless of whether there's an existing connection (this is due to the 
vagueness of "connected" on both TCP and 3G, it's best to either "try to send data", or 
re-connect to ensure a connection). As I said, I can't change this behaviour in the F/W.

The connect steps are:

1. a) Socket Teardown AT#SH b) Wait 1s
2. Configure the PDP context AT+CGDCONT
3. Configure TCP/IP stack : AT#SCFG
4. Activate the PDP context:  AT#SGACT
5. Connect TCP/IP to the server: AT#SD

(You might ask why the configuration steps 2,3,4 are done each connect: because
they can be updated via our application protocol. But typically the settings are constant.)

The problem we're encountering is sometimes the devices connect but cannot communicate.
The connections seem "stuck" - sometimes a few bytes get through, sometimes a whole 
command/response cycle, but often nothing. On connect about 10 commands normally are 
serviced, and if they fail the server drops the connection.

What I have found so far:

I have used a protocol analyser to establish what is going wrong: it's because the TCP 
FIN process of the AT#SH is overlapping with the TCP SYN handshake of the next connection
initiated with the AT#SD. This seems to be due to delayed final FIN-ACK packets arriving 
late - after the next connection is being initiated.

In the trace below you can see Frame 8799 arrives late, as an ACK to 8788, but it comes 
out-of-sequence in the middle of the next SYN-ACK handshake!

After this happens the modem is basically "broken". All subsequent connections 
experience payload-packet loss, with lots of ReTransmits and both sides re-sending their
payload packets as if they are not receiving the payload ACKs.

After step 1. (AT#SH) there is a 1 second pause in the F/W. We added this due to issues 
reconnecting when we first installed the HE910, (I know it is a kludge, but it was more 
to accomodate database-latency in our server state than for TCP/IP). However it seems 
this 1s delay isn't even affecting the TPC traffic, as you can see from the trace below. 
The ATSH "causes" Frame 8786 at 17:16:51.585, and the ATSD "causes" the SYN at Frame 8792 
at 17:16:51.595, but there is only 10ms between them. I have studied the firmware and can 
confirm the 1s delay code looks right, and watching the firmware in Terminal  - there IS 
a 1 second delay between the debug output of these steps - but TCP tells a different story.

I can send AT command in the firmware, in a limited manner - only one command every five 
seconds, which obviously skews manual tests to nice and slow. If I send +++, AT#SH during
connection A, then trigger the connection event, the device will connect successfully.
This is intriguing, as Step 1. of connecting is performing an AT#SH anyway. 
So I can conclude one of two things: either we need to send an AT#SH "earlier" (i.e.
wait longer before connecting with AT#SD), or send two of them (less likely).

I understand that this is an area of common problems in applications. Even in the Wikipedia
page on TCP/IP it mentions the risks of applications breaking the OSI model and falling 
foul of the TCP teardown handshake if used for application-level session termination. 
I'd love to add a nice "Goodbye" to our our application protocol, but that's not a 
viable option in the medium term... I'd like to get our two modems' TCP stacks aligned.

The server opens a new socket for the incoming connection, on the same IP/Port
combination. The Node and the VB both create a new socket resource from a listening parent
port, so I'm pretty sure at the server end nothing is being "reused" (it was a suspicion).
Unfortunately I have limited vision into the modem's TCP stack, only using AT#SI and SO
which give basic and seemingly non-realtime info. e.g. when the socket is closed at the 
server end, AT#SO still shows the IP/Port locally on the modem, like it hasn't received 
the FIN teardown.

From a fresh boot, the device can "reconnect" successfully around four times until 
the "jam" happens. This is strangely reliable to 4 +-1 connections. It can also be "reset" 
by waiting for some hours. So, (sorry) it feels like the modem just gets flustered.
(Again, I did suspect our telco was "limiting" our connections, but cross-telco tests are 
just too similar. And consider in production we have thousands of these devices and just 
one of them can trigger this behaviour. It's just not statistically likely they could
"notice" four connections within the hundreds of others?)

The final piece of behaviour is when the connection is "jammed" i.e not transmitting 
data, the server receives a RST (ECONNRESET in Node, just a Error in VB) after 30-60s. 
(Only if we disable our quicker application-level connection termination, so this went 
unnoticed for a long time). After this reset, however AT#SO still shows it as connected 
(with an IP), so again at first I felt it was some 3G/AP/gateway dropping the connection 
in the middle but not telling the client. However due to the consistency of the problem
 across Telcos and networks, I now find this hard to believe, and just think the AT 
 responses aren't "up to date" with reality.

This typical TCP trace shows (my interpretation so far, which might not be right)

- Connection A, Syn/Ack OK
- Our app protocol starts and completes at Frame 8197   17:16:01
- Then an event occurs which initiates another connection B
- First Step 1. tries to teardown, Frame 8786 starts the FIN handshake
- The teardown gets to Frame 8788   17:16:51.58
- Then the next connection B starts at frame 8792   17:16:51.59
- This goes OK until interrupted with the final Fin Ack from connection A at frame 8799 
  (perhaps this is ignored?)
- The application protocol tries to commence again but the first 13 byte message doesn't 
  get ACKed and is ReTransmitted many times...
- Our server resends the first command, doubling the buffer size at frame 8978
- Our server times out and drops the connection sending a Fin at 9016

Trace

```
Frame   TIME                REL TIME    SOURCE          DEST    SEQ ACK     FLAGS       WINDOW  PAYLOAD BYTES       

8003    17:15:55.9409634    703.7329764 CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   0   0 (0x0) ......S.    65000   0   Flags=......S., SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=0, Seq=316432024, Ack=0, Win=65000 (  ) = 65000    vb6.exe
8004    17:15:55.9410316    0.0000682   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   0   1       ...A..S.    8192    0   Flags=...A..S., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=17790, PayloadLen=0, Seq=319387462, Ack=316432025, Win=8192 ( Scale factor not supported ) = 8192    vb6.exe
8016    17:15:58.5707216    2.6296900   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   1   1       ...A....    65000   0   Flags=...A...., SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=0, Seq=316432025, Ack=319387463, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000  vb6.exe
8037    17:15:58.8632583    0.2925367   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   1 - 14  1   ...AP...    65000   13  Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=17790, PayloadLen=13, Seq=319387463 - 319387476, Ack=316432025, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000 vb6.exe
8039    17:15:59.0105830    0.1473247   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   1   14      ...A....    65000   0   Flags=...A...., SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=0, Seq=316432025, Ack=319387476, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000  vb6.exe
8041    17:15:59.1006112    0.0900282   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   1 - 7   14  ...AP...    65000   6   Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=6, Seq=316432025 - 316432031, Ack=319387476, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000  vb6.exe
8068    17:15:59.2997681    0.1991569   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   14  7       ...A....    64994   0   Flags=...A...., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=17790, PayloadLen=0, Seq=319387476, Ack=316432031, Win=64994 (scale factor 0x0) = 64994  vb6.exe
8071    17:15:59.3590861    0.0593180   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   14 - 19 7   ...AP...    64994   5   Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=17790, PayloadLen=5, Seq=319387476 - 319387481, Ack=316432031, Win=64994 (scale factor 0x0) = 64994  vb6.exe
8076    17:15:59.5106103    0.1515242   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   7   19      ...A....    65000   0   Flags=...A...., SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=0, Seq=316432031, Ack=319387481, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000  vb6.exe
8078    17:15:59.6005478    0.0899375   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   7 - 28  19  ...AP...    65000   21  Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=21, Seq=316432031 - 316432052, Ack=319387481, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000 vb6.exe
8100    17:15:59.7989459    0.1983981   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   19  28      ...A....    64973   0   Flags=...A...., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=17790, PayloadLen=0, Seq=319387481, Ack=316432052, Win=64973 (scale factor 0x0) = 64973  vb6.exe
8110    17:15:59.9164691    0.1175232   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   19 - 37 28  ...AP...    64973   18  Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=17790, PayloadLen=18, Seq=319387481 - 319387499, Ack=316432052, Win=64973 (scale factor 0x0) = 64973 vb6.exe
8114    17:16:00.0005725    0.0841034   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   28  37      ...A....    65000   0   Flags=...A...., SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=0, Seq=316432052, Ack=319387499, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000  vb6.exe
8120    17:16:00.2005077    0.1999352   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   28 - 34 37  ...AP...    65000   6   Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=6, Seq=316432052 - 316432058, Ack=319387499, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000  vb6.exe
8127    17:16:00.2509607    0.0504530   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   37 - 42 34  ...AP...    64967   5   Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=17790, PayloadLen=5, Seq=319387499 - 319387504, Ack=316432058, Win=64967 (scale factor 0x0) = 64967  vb6.exe
8131    17:16:00.5004721    0.2495114   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   34  42      ...A....    65000   0   Flags=...A...., SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=0, Seq=316432058, Ack=319387504, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000  vb6.exe
8132    17:16:00.5004721    0.0000000   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   34 - 43 42  ...AP...    65000   9   Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=9, Seq=316432058 - 316432067, Ack=319387504, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000  vb6.exe
8160    17:16:00.6603237    0.1598516   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   42 - 49 43  ...AP...    64958   7   Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=17790, PayloadLen=7, Seq=319387504 - 319387511, Ack=316432067, Win=64958 (scale factor 0x0) = 64958  vb6.exe
8162    17:16:00.7505392    0.0902155   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   43  49      ...A....    65000   0   Flags=...A...., SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=0, Seq=316432067, Ack=319387511, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000  vb6.exe
8168    17:16:00.9005226    0.1499834   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   43 - 55 49  ...AP...    65000   12  Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=12, Seq=316432067 - 316432079, Ack=319387511, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000 vb6.exe
8197    17:16:01.1093181    0.2087955   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   49  55      ...A....    64946   0   Flags=...A...., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=17790, PayloadLen=0, Seq=319387511, Ack=316432079, Win=64946 (scale factor 0x0) = 64946  vb6.exe
8786    17:16:51.5853712    50.4760531  CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   55  49      ...A...F    65000   0   Flags=...A...F, SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=0, Seq=316432079, Ack=319387511, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000  vb6.exe
8787    17:16:51.5854172    0.0000460   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   49  56      ...A....    64946   0   Flags=...A...., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=17790, PayloadLen=0, Seq=319387511, Ack=316432080, Win=64946 (scale factor 0x0) = 64946  vb6.exe
8788    17:16:51.5860033    0.0005861   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   49  56      ...A...F    64946   0   Flags=...A...F, SrcPort=50008, DstPort=17790, PayloadLen=0, Seq=319387511, Ack=316432080, Win=64946 (scale factor 0x0) = 64946  vb6.exe
8792    17:16:51.5954781    0.0094748   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   0   0 (0x0) ......S.    65000   0   Flags=......S., SrcPort=39522, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=0, Seq=1817440308, Ack=0, Win=65000 (  ) = 65000   vb6.exe
8793    17:16:51.5955252    0.0000471   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   0   1       ...A..S.    8192    0   Flags=...A..S., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=39522, PayloadLen=0, Seq=4287314964, Ack=1817440309, Win=8192 ( Scale factor not supported ) = 8192  vb6.exe
8799    17:16:51.7152606    0.1197354   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   56  50      ...A....    64999   0   Flags=...A...., SrcPort=17790, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=0, Seq=316432080, Ack=319387512, Win=64999 (scale factor 0x0) = 64999  vb6.exe
8801    17:16:51.7351969    0.0199363   CLIENT_IP   SERVER_IP   1   1       ...A....    65000   0   Flags=...A...., SrcPort=39522, DstPort=50008, PayloadLen=0, Seq=1817440309, Ack=4287314965, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000    vb6.exe
8821    17:16:52.0333514    0.2981545   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   1 - 14  1   ...AP...    65000   13  Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=39522, PayloadLen=13, Seq=4287314965 - 4287314978, Ack=1817440309, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000  vb6.exe
8846    17:16:52.4579548    0.4246034   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   1 - 14  1   ...AP...    65000   13  [ReTransmit #8821]Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=39522, PayloadLen=13, Seq=4287314965 - 4287314978, Ack=1817440309, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000    vb6.exe
8855    17:16:53.3003681    0.8424133   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   1 - 14  1   ...AP...    65000   13  [ReTransmit #8821]Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=39522, PayloadLen=13, Seq=4287314965 - 4287314978, Ack=1817440309, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000    vb6.exe
8875    17:16:54.9852348    1.6848667   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   1 - 14  1   ...AP...    65000   13  [ReTransmit #8821]Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=39522, PayloadLen=13, Seq=4287314965 - 4287314978, Ack=1817440309, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000    vb6.exe
8890    17:16:56.6729734    1.6877386   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   1 - 14  1   ...AP...    65000   13  [ReTransmit #8821]Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=39522, PayloadLen=13, Seq=4287314965 - 4287314978, Ack=1817440309, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000    vb6.exe
8909    17:16:58.3734032    1.7004298   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   1 - 14  1   ...AP...    65000   13  [ReTransmit #8821]Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=39522, PayloadLen=13, Seq=4287314965 - 4287314978, Ack=1817440309, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000    vb6.exe
8921    17:17:01.7429692    3.3695660   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   1 - 14  1   ...AP...    65000   13  [ReTransmit #8821]Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=39522, PayloadLen=13, Seq=4287314965 - 4287314978, Ack=1817440309, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000    vb6.exe
8978    17:17:08.4665817    6.7236125   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   1 - 27  1   ...AP...    65000   26  [ReTransmit #8821]Flags=...AP..., SrcPort=50008, DstPort=39522, PayloadLen=26, Seq=4287314965 - 4287314991, Ack=1817440309, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000    vb6.exe
9016    17:17:12.2738575    3.8072758   SERVER_IP   CLIENT_IP   27  1       ...A...F    65000   0   Flags=...A...F, SrcPort=50008, DstPort=39522, PayloadLen=0, Seq=4287314991, Ack=1817440309, Win=65000 (scale factor 0x0) = 65000    vb6.exe
```

Observations (with limited TCP knowledge)

- All the data and Fin packets have their Ack bit set - which looks unusual to me.
- The fin handshake is a four-way, but looks like the server is trying a three-way, by 
  including a Fin in the Ack of the client's Fin. Perhaps this is due to the above,
  but perhaps this is causing a problem, where the modem is doing a four way teardown 
  but the server is trying to do a three way teardown? But it also sends a standalone Ack.
- I don't understand how the ReTransmit happens so quickly? 
  Frame 8846    17:16:52.45 is sent only 420ms after the original. Surely this isn't 
  long enough to timeout receiving an ACK? Am I perhaps missing an underlying IP error 
  response packet because I'm only tracing TCP level? Otherwise how did it know to re-transmit?

So finally - my question.

**How can I, purely with AT commands, reliably teardown a TCP/IP socket, and establish 
a new connection on a new socket to the same Port/IP with no chance of delayed teardown 
packets arriving out of sequence.**

Or more specifically, how can I make the HE910 modem do this the same as the UC864 does quite successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem actually turned out to be a bug in the Telit HE910 firmware v12.00.04.

Glyn said they were confident the upgraded would fix this problem, and the changelog had many bugfixes which looked related.

After upgrading to v12.00.06 all the problems went away.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, I have managed to solve this but not necessarily answer the underlying question.

I managed to get a 2s delay added to the firmware (replacing the 1s delay described) between teardown and re-connect, as it was a simple change.

This completely fixes the behaviour and enabled me to do some further analysis on the timing over 20 re-connections.

It turns out the HE-910 modem has a periodic cycle of two network latency levels. It alternates been 900ms and 1,200ms every couple of minutes. This means the first few connections (which I can do every 30s), will succeed with a 1s delay in the code, but when it gets to the 1.2s delay, the FIN-ACK packets spill into the next connection.

[image: FIN ACK latency graph]

This graph shows the "distance" in time between the FIN/ACK sequence and the next SYN/ACK handshake, when there is a 2s delay between the ATSH command and the ATSD command.  It clearly has a periodic variation which occasionally takes it over the edge of the 1s pause.

So it turns out that my previous kludge of a 1s delay was *only just* working. Longer testing a year ago would have shown this up.

So while the 2s delay is just a longer kludge, it seems there is enough headroom for this to be safe. I am doing further benchmarking to see if we could ever risk approaching 2s latency.

It's possible this is the "Delayed ACK" feature of some TCP/IP stacks but 1.2s seems extremely long. The modem doesn't have a command to control the TCP_NODELAY option so I can't test it.

It also seems the AT#SH command is asynchronous, in that the OK is returned before the teardown *even starts*. Otherwise the initial FIN would always be offset by 1s or 2s, whereas in the graph above both FIN and ACK are delayed by 0.8ms plus the time between them.

I will also benchmark the UC864 using the 2s firmware, to get the same graph, which should shed more light on the underlying cause.